# How to make my Luis.ai entity to recognize string values that contains underscore '_'

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to create an entity that accepts string values with underscore (eg., first_sec_last).For instance I created an *entity named  Stream* (entity type :*simple*).But when I type in value "first_sec_last" it is identifying my StreamName as "first" instead of "first_sec_last".
Any suggestions to make my entity recognize string values with underscore?

Here is a screen shot showing my entity values are not recognized when input string contains '_' eg: analyze First_Name

[image]

Another screen shot showing my entity values are correctly recognized when input string do not contain '_'  eg: analyze FirstName

[image]

My Question :

How to make Luis recognize my entity when input string contains '_' ?

Comment: Could you please add sample json of the response and also the text you are sending in the request?

Comment: eg., text I am sending  'First_Last' and the text is not recognized

Comment: I'll double check with someone who works on the LUIS team, however I suspect you  might not be able to get LUIS to recognize something that contains an underscore as one word, because of how LUIS tokenizes under-the-hood.

Comment: Ok, confirmed, you can't do anything with regards to how LUIS tokenizes words. The only thing you can do is add A LOT of training data via sample utterances and labeling the whole underscored word with the entity. I say "a lot" because it would be the same undertaking as adding a foreign or "made-up" word to LUIS's vocab, as it starts with 0 data on that particular word